# Crashlytics NDK symbols and Gradle tasks

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have a question that mostly relates to gradle.

I'm using Crashlytics to report NDK crashes in my Android app.
I have a task in build.gradle that calls ndk-build and compiles the cpp files into an .so file.
At the end of this task I want to call a task that uploads generated symbols mapping to Crashlytics.

After installing the Fabric plugin in Android Studio, I saw there are some new tasks that were added to the Gradle tab. One of them is
crashlyticsUploadSymbols[buildType][flavour] where buildType and flavour indicate which buildtype and flavour is currently selected.

This task does seem to upload a symbols file.

My question is,
Is it possible to call this task from within build.gradle?
Currently I use a manual call in Android Studio's terminal tab in the form of:

./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbols[buildType][flavour]

Is it possible to call this task somehow from within build.gradle?

To call this task I use finalizedBy at the end of the buildNdk task, so once buildNdk has finished, the upload task will execute.

Also very important, how can I get the current buildType and flavour so I am able to add it to the crashlyticsUploadSymbols call?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here.

This was also answered on the Twitter Community forum's, but sharing the same answer here.

Option 1:

If you only want or need to upload symbols for your release builds, then you can set `crashlticsUploadSymbolsRelease` as the `finalizedBy` task for your ndk-build task.

Option 2:
If you have multiple variant-based tasks, you can do something like:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
    def task = project.task ("ndkBuild${variantName}")
    task.finalizedBy project.("crashlyticsUploadSymbols${variantName}")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, i get `Error:(101, 0) Cannot add task ':App:externalNativeBuildProdDebug' as a task with that name already exists.
<a href="openFile:/path/to/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>` so still have to upload manually :(

Comment: Sounds like you may have a duplicate task, but I'd recommend posting a new question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

The following did the job for me:

```
android {
...
    afterEvaluate {
        assembleDebug.finalizedBy(crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug)
        assembleRelease.finalizedBy(crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease)
    }
}
```